# How to use EUR in Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have set-up everything I need to test my app in the Paypal Sandbox.

However, I was having this issue: My app was submitting transactions in EUR, but, apparently, the sandbox needed USD, otherwise the transaction would not complete. I changed it to USD and everything worked fine.

So, now I need to change my sandbox settings to accept EUR, but I cannot find any place to do this.

How can I set my sandbox account so it can accept EUR as the default and convert USD to EUR?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default currency is decided by the country you choose when you create the account.
To automatically accepet transactions that are not in your default currency you can choose "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold:" from [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-pref)

Comment: Thanks. I actually found that and changed it, but I see now the change didn't take the first time. It works fine now.

Comment: [for reference](https://go.eway.io/s/article/ka828000000L2mRAAS/Can-I-change-the-Currency-in-my-Sandbox): here says that is not possible

Comment: Just the case to : go to your Business Dashboard> payment preferences > Yes, accept and convert them to dollar* (*your default currency)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new paypal sandbox account from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)

[image: here]

**Select country from here..**

[image]

Note: The default currency is decided by the country you choose when you create the account.
And the default paypal sandbox Accounts consist the default/local currency..Best option is to create new sandbox account.

Comment: Is this possible by editing an already existent sandbox?

Comment: I guess no..default sandbox doesn't allow